# Find missing quarters in time series

Tags: javascript, datetime, time-series, momentjs

I am trying to see how could I fill the missing financial quarters of a time series like this in Javascript:

```
["2012-Q2","2012-Q4","2013-Q4","2014-Q1","2014-Q2","2014-Q3",
 "2014-Q4","2015-Q1","2015-Q2","2015-Q3","2015-Q4","2016-Q1",
 "2016-Q2","2016-Q3","2016-Q4","2017-Q1","2017-Q2","2017-Q3",
 "2017-Q4","2018-Q1"]
```

- I would like somehow to get a time series with the missing elements i.e. for each year I should see 4 "dates".
- I don't mind ignoring the first quarter before the first element `"2012-Q2"` and the last 3 quarters after the last element "2018-Q1".

I know `moment.js` has functions like `quarter()` or `fquarter()` (via a plugin), but I am looking for something closer to the other way around. I already have the quarters (as date-strings), and I have to parse them as date objects.

I need to fill the "quarter holes" in between those input string values.

In my case I probably need to parse first those date-strings in that custom format to make them something `moment` could understand, but I am a bit lost. In here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ a potential format could involve `Y` for years and `Q` for quarters, but I am not sure how to escape the literal `Q` inside every input date-string of that array?

Also assuming I could somehow parse all those date strings into `moment` objects, then I am not sure how that could help in filling the holes?

I can not find a pure javascript solution involving date types.

Another approach could be to parse those date-strings and get the year and the quarter number using `substring` and then manually filling the holes checking year/quarter pairs, is there anything simpler than this?

Comment: what result do you expect from the given data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want a full list of quarters between the first one of your input array until the last one, you can:

- parse with moment the first and the last element of your array, using [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) with `'YYYY[-Q]Q'` as format parameter, see [Escaping charaters](https://momentjs.com/docs/#escaping-characters) section of the docs.
- loop from `start` to `end` using [`isSameOrBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/) (or other [query](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) functions) adding 1 quarter on each iteration ([`add(1, 'Q')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/))

Here a live sample:

```js
var quarters = ["2012-Q2","2012-Q4","2013-Q4","2014-Q1","2014-Q2","2014-Q3",
 "2014-Q4","2015-Q1","2015-Q2","2015-Q3","2015-Q4","2016-Q1",
 "2016-Q2","2016-Q3","2016-Q4","2017-Q1","2017-Q2","2017-Q3",
 "2017-Q4","2018-Q1"];

var format = 'YYYY[-Q]Q';
var start = moment(quarters[0], format);
var end = moment(quarters[quarters.length-1], format);

var results = [];
while( start.isSameOrBefore(end) ){
  results.push(start.format(format));
  start.add(1, 'Q');
}
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a function that returns the quarters from a particular range?

```
function getQuarters(startYear, endYear){
  var times = [];
  for(var i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++){
    times.push(i + "-Q1");
    times.push(i + "-Q2");
    times.push(i + "-Q3");
    times.push(i + "-Q4");
  }
  return times;
}
```

Calling:

```
getQuarters(2017,2017);
```

Returns:

```
["2017-Q1", "2017-Q2", "2017-Q3", "2017-Q4"]
```

Comment: Do that, then follow [How to get the difference between two arrays in Javascript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1187518) to get the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get an array with the missing values, you could take a start quarter and cehck against the given data for either pushing the quartal or incremet the index of the array.

```js
function incQ(time) {
    time[1]++;
    if (time[1] === 5) {
        time[0]++;
        time[1] = 1;
    }
}

var quarters = ["2012-Q2", "2012-Q4", "2013-Q4", "2014-Q1", "2014-Q2", "2014-Q3", "2014-Q4", "2015-Q1", "2015-Q2", "2015-Q3", "2015-Q4", "2016-Q1", "2016-Q2", "2016-Q3", "2016-Q4", "2017-Q1", "2017-Q2", "2017-Q3", "2017-Q4", "2018-Q1"],
    actual = quarters[0].split('-Q'),
    missing = [],
    i = 0;

while (i < quarters.length) {
    if (actual.join('-Q') !== quarters[i]) {
        missing.push(actual.join('-Q'));
    } else {
        i++;
    }
    incQ(actual);
}

console.log(missing);
```